# How do I find out reason of missing packets in response to `sendto` syscall?

Tags: linux, networking, debugging, socket

`strace ... -e sendto` shows a successful (i.e. positive return value) outcome of trying to send a UDP datagram somewhere, but `tcpdump -i any` in that network namespace does not show anything relevant in response to it.

How do I debug why `sendto` does not lead to an outgoing packet? Is there a tool which traces the request across all the layers (routing, traffic control, nftables, etc.) and output when information from within the datagram disappeared from the kernel? Or is there some guide / document with a checklist with an *exhausive* list of reasons why it can happen?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no guarantee that a machine can hear its own packets, especially UDP packets.  So if you ran tcpdump on the same machine as sendto(), then you have found expected behavior even if the sendto worked.
2. If any router (or other network device) in between the source and destination can't send the packet for any reason (memory, bandwidth, power glitches, cosmic rays, routing loops, etc.), the UDP packet will be dropped (or duplicated or received out of order) without notification.
3. There is no guarantee that a UDP packet will be delivered at all.  If the kernel is out of memory, it could be dropped.  If the network is full at the time you tried to send it, it could be dropped.  If the receiving machine was too busy at the time, it could be dropped.   So even if sendto worked and you ran tcpdump on a separate machine, tcpdump still might not see the packet.

The only notification the sender can get of a packet not being delivered is if the target actively refuses to accept the packet, or if routers in the middle decide there's no route possible to deliver the packet.  And these notifications are also not guaranteed for any particular packet, and likely will be sent only once for an entire cohort of packets.

If you don't like these conditions, don't use UDP.  It wasn't named "unreliable datagram protocol" for arbitrary reasons.  The point of UDP is a delayed packet is a useless packet.  UDP optimizes for speed, not reliability.  The protocols in TCP that insure reliably transmitted and in order packets can also cause packets to be delayed, throttled, held, buffered, disassembled, reassembled, collated, and batched.  Technically, tcp doesn't even provide packets, it provides a datastream that only coincidentally has any packet boundaries, and these "boundaries" are not guaranteed to be the same on sender and receiver.

Comment: "If the kernel is out of memory, it could be dropped. If the network is full at the time you tried to send it, it could be dropped." -> so I want it to output the drop reason, both if transient and if caused by a misconfiguration.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that records these reasons, or even if it is possible to record them.   If the kernel doesn't have memory to keep the packet, what makes it you think it has memory to record why it dropped it?   Although there are counters in the network interface for dropped incoming and outgoing packets.  Also, if the packet was dropped by a router in the middle, the only record either end will get of this is the packet not arriving at the destination.

Comment: There are four difficult things in networking:  4. Exactly once delivery of a packet.  1. In order packet delivery.  4. Exactly once delivery of a packet.

Comment: "dropped by a router in the middle" -> `tcpdump` is running in the same network namespace as the program issuing `sendto`, so it implies that it is running on the same host (without routers in between) and dropped packet are likely due to a misconfiguraion. The tool or checklist requested is intended to help finding this misconfiguration.

Comment: Very likely tcpdump will not hear packets sent from the local host, only packets sent to the local host.

Comment: typically `tcpdump` sees all of the packets to local host, from local host, within local host (e.g. to `127.0.0.1`) or routed though the local host.